# Developing application for iphone and ipad both

Tags: iphone, ipad, storyboard

Hi I am beginner for IOS development. I started building application for iphone. But now I want to build same application for ipad as well. I am well known to android platform but don't know much about IOS platform. So need some good suggestion. my application UI is not that much different for iphone and ipad. Only at certain point it is different. 
So my quires like this. 
Whether we need two different applications for iphone and ipad or we can use same application for both?
How to manage UI for both devices iphone and ipad?

I am using story board for UI development. Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Create a `Universal App` with one Storyboard for iPhone and one Storyboard for iPad. If you are new to iOS, the Stanford iOS course on iTunes (`Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad`) shows how to convert an iPhone app to a Universal app that also has an iPad UI.

Answer (score 2):

Back to [App Design Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AppDesignBasics/AppDesignBasics.html), read it all and specifically [“Creating a Universal App.”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW24)

Answer (score 1):

No, you need not to create two different applications. You just need to add a different viewController for the iPad. You can manage the view in your code as well by putting checks for iPhone or iPad Device.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ready iPhone application with Storyboard. And now you need to create iPad or iOS universal application. The longest and hardest way is to create whole Storyboard manually from the beginning. The easiest and quickest way is to convert iPhone Storyboard into iPad Storyboard.

> When you have only iPhone application.

Duplicate iPhone Storyboard in Finder and call it “MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard”.
Add new Storyboard into project.
If you have text editor like “TextWrangler”, “BBEdit”, “Code” – open copied Storyboard in it.
If you don’t have – click mouse + Control (or right mouse button) on this new Storyboard in Xcode and select “Open As”->”Sourcecode”.
Search for string targetRuntime=”iOS.CocoaTouch” and change it to targetRuntime=”iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad”.
Save it and reopen in Xcode – it may be arranged wrong but it is easier to rearrange it than create from the beginning.

> When you created universal iOS application.

In this case you already have empty iPad Storyboard. Open iPhone Storyboard, select all (Command+A), copy (Command+C) and paste (Command+V) it into iPad Storyboard.
Don’t forget to move the entry point from the empty Storyboard to copied storyboard before compiling or you wil have crash.

Comment: Is there any way where I can use same story board for both iphone and ipad as well with some conditions for iphone and ipad ?

Comment: I have never tried this, but I would suggest to go with the standard implementation.
When we create a Universal project, XCODE creates 2 Storyboards, for iPhone and iPad. It is as per the defined rules by Apple.

Also its easy to manage than making mess of code. Keep your code simple & clean and use the given features for better implementation and performance of the app.

Comment: Yeah sure. But I can use common controllers right ?

Comment: In story board for iPhone/iPod you will not be able to select a size for iPad, which will create problems. But still if you want to then its SOFT WARE, means you can develop it the way you want to, its another thing that there are some limits but Jail broken apps developers go beyond the limits and they achieve what they want

Comment: Never forget to accept the answer, if it helped you :)